# Covariance on dictionary key

Tags: c#

Assuming one has a method producing `IReadOnlyDictionary<DerivedType, object>`, how does one provide this object to a method taking `IReadOnlyDictionary<BaseType, object>`? Why does casting not work?

Comment: I think it works by default

Comment: You could do `var baseTypeKeyDictionary = derivedTypeKeyDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => (BaseType)kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);`  That of course creates a new dictionary which may or may not suit your needs.

Comment: `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is invariant, it doesn't support generic variance

Answer (score 0):

`IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not have covariant parameters for two reasons. First, `TKey` cannot be covariant because it is also used in an input position (in `ContainsKey`), and both `TKey` and `TValue` cannot be covariant because it also implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` and `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a value type and thus invariant.

Fortunately, even though the runtime cannot cast between the types, it is easy to adapt one to the other. First, if the underlying collection is actually a `Dictionary<DerivedType, object>`, this is one of the cases when one could inherit from `Dictionary`:

```
class BaseKeyDictionary<TBaseKey, TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue> where TKey : class, TBaseKey
{
    TValue IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.this[TBaseKey key] => key is TKey key2 ? this[key2] : throw new KeyNotFoundException();

    IEnumerable<TBaseKey> IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.Keys => ((IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>)this).Keys;

    IEnumerable<TValue> IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.Values => ((IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>)this).Values;

    int IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>>.Count => Count;

    bool IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.ContainsKey(TBaseKey key)
    {
        return key is TKey key2 ? ContainsKey(key2) : false;
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach(var pair in this)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    bool IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TBaseKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        if(key is TKey key2) return TryGetValue(key2, out value);
        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

And, if one does not have access to the underlying type of the dictionary, it is always possible to create a wrapper for it to implement the interface via the original object:

```
class BaseKeyDictionaryWrapper<TBaseKey, TKey, TValue> : IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue> where TKey : class, TBaseKey
{
    readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict;

    public BaseKeyDictionaryWrapper(IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        this.dict = dict;
    }

    TValue IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.this[TBaseKey key] => key is TKey key2 ? dict[key2] : throw new KeyNotFoundException();

    IEnumerable<TBaseKey> IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.Keys => dict.Keys;

    IEnumerable<TValue> IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.Values => dict.Values;

    int IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>>.Count => dict.Count;

    bool IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.ContainsKey(TBaseKey key)
    {
        return key is TKey key2 ? dict.ContainsKey(key2) : false;
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach(var pair in dict)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TBaseKey, TValue>(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }

    bool IReadOnlyDictionary<TBaseKey, TValue>.TryGetValue(TBaseKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        if(key is TKey key2) return dict.TryGetValue(key2, out value);
        value = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```